# Can't call my json function in laravel 4.2

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

So in my 'edit records' view I have this two dropdrown the first one contains the main category and the second one should contain values based from the main category chosen is the first dropdown. So I implemented an ajax call for this in my view, here is how the dropdown code looks like

```
<select name="category" id="category" class="dds">
                @foreach($mCategories as $lists)
                    <option value="{{$lists->maincategoryid}}">{{$lists->maincategoryname}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>


            <h6>Doc SubClass 1</h6>
            <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class="dds">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
```

then I have this in my script to call the ajax function

```
<script>

        $('#category').on('change' , function(e){
            console.log(e);
            var cat_id = e.target.value;
            alert(cat_id);

            //ajax
            $.getJSON('ajax-subcat?cat_id=' + cat_id , function(data){
                console.log(data);

                $('#subcategory').empty();

                $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
                {
                  $('#subcategory').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.Object.subcategoryid +'">' + subcatObj.subcategoryname +'</option>');
                });

            });
        });

    </script>
```

and the code for the ajax call is in my routes and here is how it looks

```
Route::get('ajax-subcat' ,function()
{
  $cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
  $subcategories = DB::table('nsa_subcategory')
                ->where('maincategoryid' , '=' , $cat_id)
                ->get();
  return Response::json($subcategories);
});
```

as you can see, in my script I tried to log the `data` after the `$getJSON` to check whether or not it went in but I am not getting anything. The thing is I also used this codes in my creating of records so i don't know what my error is now. any ideas? thanks in advance!